# What is variance of $Var\left[(X-\mu)^k-E[(X-\mu)^{k}]-kE[(X-\mu)^{k-1}](X-\mu)\right]=?$

Tags: probability, analysis

For $k\ge 1$, if $X$ is a r.v. and $\mu=E[X]$, what is variance of
$$Var\left[(X-\mu)^k-E[(X-\mu)^{k}]-kE[(X-\mu)^{k-1}](X-\mu)\right]=?$$

Let $\mu_k=E[(X-\mu)^k]$. Then
$$
Var\left[(X-\mu)^k-kE[(X-\mu)^{k-1}](X-\mu)\right]=Var[(X-\mu)^k]+(kE[(X-\mu)^{k-1}])^2Var[(X-\mu)]=Var[(X-\mu)^k]+k^2\mu_{k-1}^2\mu_2
$$

But I know the answer should be
$$
\mu_{2k}-\mu_k^2+k^2\mu_{k-1}^2\mu_2-2k\mu_{k-1}\mu_{k+1}
$$

How to reach out the final result?

Comment: The variance of a sum of RVs is not necessarily the sum of the RV's individual variances. (It is true when the RVs are independent, but $(X-\mu)^k$ and $X-\mu$ are not independent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,
$$\text{Var}(Y + Z) = \text{Var}(Y) + \text{Var}(Z) + 2 \text{Cov}(Y, Z).$$
You've forgotten the covariance term in your computation.

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}((X-\mu)^k, k\mu_{k-1} (X-\mu))
&= k\mu_{k-1}\text{Cov}((X-\mu)^k, X-\mu)
\\
&= k\mu_{k-1}([E[(X-\mu)^{k+1}] - E[(X-\mu)^k] E[X-\mu])
\\
&= k\mu_{k-1} \mu_{k+1},
\end{align}
which is the last term in the answer.

Finally, your first term is $\text{Var}((X-\mu)^k) = E[(X-\mu)^{2k}] - (E[(X-\mu)^k])^2 = \mu_{2k} - \mu_k^2$.